# Yii beforeAction compatibility issue

Tags: php, yii

I just started learning Yii today and dont know anything in it, so this question might sound really stupid. While testing some demos apps in yii, I came across this error message.

Strict standards: Declaration of SiteController::beforeAction() should be compatible with CController::beforeAction($action) in C:\wamp\www\protected\controllers\SiteController.php

Can anyone help me, what is the issue here and how can i fix this.

Here is the beforeAction function

```
protected function beforeAction(CAction $action) {
    $user = Yii::app()->session->get('user');
    /* is valid user check and assign user details to $user*/
   Yii::app()->session->add('user',$user);
   if(!isset($user)) {
       //redirect(login page);
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Note: I knw this is not the proper way to learn something new but im kinda short in time. So pls bear with me.

Answer (score 2):

You are extending a method that is inherited from `CController`, but the parameter list doesn't match up. Notice that the error says that `CController` allows passing of the `$action` parameter. That means when you extend the method, it should also have at least that parameter.

That is not a Yii specific thing, but rather something PHP (with strict standards on) is warning you about.

For something that is Yii related, make sure that you do one of the following with your `beforeAction($action)` method:

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    ...code...

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

OR

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    ...code...

    return true;
}
```

Which pattern you use depends on what `...code...` you are placing, and where you want to short circuit the action, if at all. Just keep in mind that you MUST return true from this method, unless you wish to stop the action from executing.

Comment: thanks, this is how the beforeAction function is defined in the extended controller

public function beforeAction(CAction $action)

Comment: @iamagent If you are still getting the error, can you edit your question and show what your `beforeAction` method looks like. Also, make sure you use `protected` and not `public`, as the parent is `protected` and that can cause this error too.

Comment: i have edited the questioon and have added the beforeAction method